# SQL Select a date which is exactly 30 days later

Tags: mysql, sql

My current code select all the date that's less than 30days, how can i select date that's exactly 30 days later,many thanks

```html
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patientvaccinedetail WHERE ( NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function for this, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM patientvaccinedetail
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), yourdatecolumn) = 30;
```

Comment: don't you mean `WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), yourdatecolumn) = -30;` ?

Comment: @FMashiro updated the answer, got confused by the statement `select all the date that's less than 30days` in the question. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Also, it should be negative 30 (according to the docs at least) :P

Comment: It will be negative only if dates in the table are greater than today's date. But that's not specified..

Comment: In his query, he uses `NOW () - INTERVAL 1 MONTH` but he wants later, so he basically wants `NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH` which would be greater than `now` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use DATE_ADD(`your_field_name`, INTERVAL X DAYS) method to add date to the date that exists in your table.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

select
*
from x

where 
trunc(something) = trunc(sysdate-30)